# How do you run code from a repository on github?

Tags: python, github

so i made a simple game using pygame, and I made a repository for it on github. Now, I want to be able to run the code on github, **without** downloading it or cloning it to another computer. what i mean is that can you run the github code r**ight on your browser**. Is there any way I could do this? thx!

Comment: Nope. Github is a code repository, not an app host. Check out Heroku, AWS, Google App Engine, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: This question is a bit vague though actually. You can't run code directly from GitHub as it's just a VCS based cloud service. But you can run your code by using Codespaces by GitHub (unfortunately, it's in beta).

Comment: pygame has to run on local computer - it can't run in web browser or remotlly. So you have to download it to run it.

Comment: if you want to run game without downloading then you should write it in JavaScript. And then you can put it on web page (maybe even on Github) and when user will visit page then web browser may load it from server and start running in web browser (using built-in JavaScript interpreter). But truth is: you don't download it manually but web browser has to download code to run it.

Comment: If you want to make a more complex game, Unity has web browser support.

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!, it can be done. If you are trying to run regular code (code that doesn't need a user interface), you can use codespaces of github. Now, regarding the pygame library, there is a web site that support this: https://replit.com/.

The site not only supports python, but many more languages, it has connection with github, so you can upload your repo.

Hope it helps!!
Cheers. :)